# Good resource/book for learning Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch

I have have been trying to learn Objective-C for a little bit now. I was wondering if anyone knows of good online references guides/courses related to the topic that are good know of any good books related to this topic.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.quora.com/iOS-Application-Development-1/What-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-iOS-development

Comment: Also the good tutorial for beginners : Link 1) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/  Link 2) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three great free references for learning objective-C are:

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/  -- Ray Wenderlich provides high quality tutorials for many topics ranging from basic to advances objective-c programming.
2. http://nshipster.com/ -- NSHipster is a journal of the overlooked bits in Objective-C, Swift, and Cocoa. Updated weekly.
3. http://littlebitesofcocoa.com/ -- Similar to NSHipster, utilizing short, sweet, and to the point articles for IOS and OSX development.

What I used to begin learning Objective-C and IOS development are the books:

1. Big Nerd Ranch Guide - Objective-C Programming https://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/objective-c-programming/
2. Big Nerd Ranch Guide - IOS Programming
   https://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/ios-programming/

As programming is always changing, some tutorials and methods are going to be a small bit outdated using updated versions of Xcode. If you are using a book, I would recommend downloading the version of Xcode to whatever is being used in the book.

If something is not working properly, look up errors on google or post questions on stackoverflow -- solving errors are what help you learn!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, very in depth. (would +1 but my rep here is not nearly as high as my apple.stackexchange one).

Comment: No problem! Good luck with learning!

Comment: If you're new to programming, I would also plan on learning how to use GitHub. In fact, I'd say that's the first thing you should do if you're just starting out--I wish I'd appreciated how much easier knowing how to use version control software would make my life when I was starting to learn this stuff. I strongly recommend BNR books referenced above. They are fantastic. Additionally, Stanford CS193P course is good, however it's like drinking water from a firehose if you're new to iOS.